# I solved the problem, but as it turned out wrong. What needs to be changed in the code?

Tags: java

I solved the problem, but as it turned out wrong, the teacher said that from java.util. *, You can only use java.util.regex. *, Help solve the problem of how to do without java.util.LinkedHashSet and java.util.Set in this situation.

What needs to be changed in the code?

***TASK***

> The task must be solved using regular expressions.
>   The method should convert input data to string of the following type (mail domain ==> list of logins separated by a comma of those users whose mailboxes are registered in this domain):
>   mail.com ==> ivanov, bush;
>   google.com ==> петров, obama

**part1.txt**

```
ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com
петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com
bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com
```

**Part1.java**

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static Util.getMatcher;

public class Part1 {

    private static final String TXTP1 = "part1.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println(convert3(Util.readFile(TXTP1)));
    }
    public static String convert3(String input) {
        String regex = "(?m)^(.+(?=;));.+;.+@(.+)(?=\\b)$";
        Matcher matcher = Util.getMatcher(regex, input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            set.add(matcher.group(2));
        }

        for (String s : set) {
            matcher = Util.getMatcher(regex, input);
            sb.append(s).append(" ==> ");
            while (matcher.find()) {
                if (s.equals(matcher.group(2))) {
                    sb.append(matcher.group(1)).append(", ");
                }
            }
            sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Util.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Util {

    private static final String ENCODING = "Cp1251";

    public static String readFile(String path) {
        String res = null;
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
            res = new String(bytes, ENCODING);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static Matcher getMatcher(String regex, String input) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        return p.matcher(input);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(readFile("part1.txt"));
}
}
```

Comment: Use a String array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small data class holding user and email domain. (A two-dimensional array of strings would work as well).

```
static class UserEmailData{
    String domain, user;
    UserEmailData(String domain, String user){
        this.domain = domain;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

The sample data you have provided is consistent, so we can iterate the input extracting user and domain using regex.

```
    String input = "ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.com\n" +
            "петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com\n" +
            "obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com\n" +
            "bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.com";

    Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?);(?:.*?)@([A-Za-z]+\\.[A-Za-z]+)");
    String [] inputLines = input.split("\n");
    UserEmailData [] usersAndDomains = new UserEmailData[inputLines.length];
    int currentLine = 0;

    for (String line : inputLines){
        Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(line);
        emailMatcher.find();
        String user = emailMatcher.group(1);
        String domain = emailMatcher.group(2);
        usersAndDomains[currentLine] = new UserEmailData(domain, user);
        currentLine++;
    }
```

Once we have the data extracted, we can sort it depending on the domain value:

```
static void sortData(UserEmailData [] data){
    for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<data.length; j++){
            if(data[i].domain.compareTo(data[j].domain)>0) {
                UserEmailData temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that the user data is sorted, printing it will give following output:

```
for(UserEmailData data : usersAndDomains){
    System.out.println(data.user + " " + data.domain);
}

петров google.com
obama google.com
ivanov mail.com
bush mail.com
```

What's left is to keep concatenating users, as long as domain remains unchanged, which is a simple task.
Using regex in this task is a bit of an overkill, as you could simply split the string by ";" and use the same approach.